# What is the difference between UI/GUI testing, functional testing and E2E testing?

Tags: functional-testing, e2e-testing, gui-testing

I would say that all three are the same, but I wonder if there is small differences between them. In the end, what I think is that you are testing user scenarios on all of them.

Comment: Good question, I looking forward to this too :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UI testing**: user interface testing. In other words, you have to make sure that all buttons, fields, labels and other elements on the screen work as assumed in a specification.

**GUI testing**: graphical user interface. You have to make sure that all elements on the screen work as mentioned in a specification and also color, font, element size and other similar stuff match design.

**Functional testing**: the process of quality assurance of a product that assumes the testing of the functions/functionalities of component or system in general, according to specification requirements.

**E2E testing**: it needs for identifying system dependencies and ensuring that the right information is passed through multiple components and systems.

Comment: The only difference between GUI and UI testing is that the former checks for styles of graphical elements while the former just checks for correctness in the functionality, isn't it?

Comment: Functional testing is the same as e2e testing also called browser testing

Answer (score 3):

Please make yourself familiar with [Hermetic Testing](https://testing.googleblog.com/2012/10/hermetic-servers.html).

[image: hermetic-testing]

You have two ways to access systems in your test:

1. You have a local service. For example an in memory database instead of the real database
2. You mock the system.

For me UI-tests work like in above picture: All tests use local resources. They are **hermetic**.

But End-to-end Tests involve other systems. Example: Your SUT (system under test) creates an email. You want to be sure that this email gets send to a server and later arrives in an Inbox. For me this contradicts with "separation of concerns". This mixes two distinct topics. First: Your application creates an email and sends it to an server. This could be handled with a mocked mail server. But end-to-end tests mix it with a second concern: You want the mail server to be alive and receive and forward mails correctly. This is not software testing, this is monitoring.

My advice: Do hermetic UI-Testing of code and do check/monitor your production system. But don't mix both concepts. I think for small environments end-to-end-tests are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that functional testing is the same as UI/GUI testing at all. consider that we talk about a mechanical domain or another which is not software; for me the functional testing, test the function;e.g. if you click on the  hard button of your microwave, it should start working. Now if instead of the buttons, your microwave has a touch screen and an OS to manage the screen, and you click on the soft button,this soft button should drive the hard button in order that he microwave functions. So for me, functional testing means testing the microwave using the hard button, but UI testing means testing the Microwave using the soft button and since soft button drives the hard button, by testing the UI, you ALSO do functional testing.
Does it make sense to oy?